# Encoding Integers with right shift

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Okay so, I have a case where I have to encode numbers with bitwise operators and then decode them

This is what I came up with to encode the number

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int lastInt = random.nextInt(24);
int howMany = 350;
int start = (lastInt & ~1337) | (howMany << lastInt);
```

The number I want to encode is `350` This works fine for the most cases and I decode the number by using

`start >> lastInt`, How ever if the number is negative such as cases like this: `System.out.println(-1593835514 >> 23);`, it doesn't print the correct encoded number, I am pretty sure this is because the first integer is negative and I can use `>>>` to shift unsigned integers, but I don't wanna do that, How can I make sure all my encoded integers decode via `>>`

Comment: How did you come up with this way of encoding a number, and what is the decoding algorithm?

Comment: To decode the int, You just have to right shift `start` with `lastInt` So printing the decoded number would be as followed `System.out.println(start >> lastInt)`, This should print `howMany`

Comment: And what reason do you have for believing that this decoding algorithm *should* give you the original int that was encoded? You have code proving that it doesn't.

Comment: @kaya3 The code does work perfectly if you shift unsigned integers by using `>>>` and if `start` if positive it does with `>>`, but if `start` is negative it does not work using `>>` which just shifts signed integers, I want it to avoid being negative output.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain why you *think* the algorithm should be correct. Clearly there is a mismatch between your thinking and the actual behaviour, but the actual behaviour is unarguable, so the only resolution is to identify the mistake in your thinking.

Comment: By the way, even if you use `>>>` then it fails e.g. for the positive number 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `random.nextInt(24)` for the shift value, it means the shift value can be in range 0..23. With a shift of 23, that only leaves 9 bits in a 32-bit number to store your value.

If the value is **unsigned**, that means supported range is **0..511**.
If the value is **signed**, that means supported range is **-256..255**.

So, if you want to allow a value like 350, your encode/decode must be unsigned, which means you must use `>>>` when decoding.

As-is, you cannot support both 350 *and* negative values. If you want larger value ranges to support that, you need to use `long`.

Comment: I don't want to use `>>>` I want to use `>>` safely with any value I put in, Should I lower the shift value range?

Comment: @Johnathan So you want to support negative numbers by using `>>`? In what range? -512..511? -1024..1023? -4096..4095? -32768..32767? Some other range? Whatever range you choose will determine the max shift you can apply.